# Why PostgreSQL doesn't use indexes on "WHERE NOT IN" conditions.

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables db100 and db60 with the same fields: x, y, z. 
Indexes are created for both the tables on field z like this:

```
CREATE INDEX db100_z_idx
  ON db100
  USING btree
  (z COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
CREATE INDEX db60_z_idx
  ON db60
  USING btree
  (z COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Trying to find z values  from db60 that don't exist in db100:

```
select db60.z from db60 where db60.z not in (select db100.z from db100)
```

As far as I understand, all the information required to execute the query is presented in the indexes. So, I would expect only indexes used. 
However it uses sequential scan on tables instead:

```
"Seq Scan on db60  (cost=0.00..25951290012.84 rows=291282 width=4)"
"  Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))"
"  SubPlan 1"
"    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..80786.26 rows=3322884 width=4)"
"          ->  Seq Scan on db100  (cost=0.00..51190.84 rows=3322884 width=4)"
```

Can someone pls explain why PostgreSQL doesn't use indexes in this example?

Both the tables contain a few millions records and execution takes a while.

I know that using a left join with "is null" condition gives better results. However, the question is about this particular syntax.

I'm on PG v 9.5

Comment: Please add the plan using `explain (analyze)`

Comment: The `z` field is obviously a `varchar` or some variant thereof. What are typical values of `z`? Specifically, can these values be long strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SubPlan 1 is for `select db100.z from db100`. You select ***all*** rows and hence an index is useless. You really want to `select DISTINCT z from db100` here and then the index should be used.

In the main query you have `select db60.z from db60 where db60.z not in ...`. Again, you select ***all*** rows except where a condition is ***not*** true, so again the index does not apply because it applies to the inverse condition.

In general, an index is only used if the planner thinks that such a use will speed up the query processing. It always depends on how many distinct values there are and how the rows are distributed over the physical pages on disk. An index to search for all rows having a column with a certain value is not the same as finding the rows that do ***not*** have that same value; the index indicates on which pages and at which locations to find the rows, but that set can not simply be inversed.

Given - in your case - that `z` is some `text` type, a meaningful "negative" index can not be constructed (this is actually almost a true-ism, although in some cases a "negative" index could be conceivable). You should look into [trigram indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtrgm.html), as these tend to work much faster than `btree` on text indexing.

You really want to extract all 291,282 rows with the same `z` value, or perhaps use a `DISTINCT` clause here too? That should speed things up quite a bit.

Comment: Yes, there are many duplicates of z values in both the tables.

Comment: Hmm, adding distinct has indeed significantly reduced processing time. However, explain still doesnt show use of indexes: "HashAggregate  (cost=70677.28..70694.77 rows=1749 width=4)"
"  Group Key: db60.z"
"  ->  Seq Scan on db60  (cost=59518.04..69949.07 rows=291282 width=4)"
"        Filter: (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1))"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  HashAggregate  (cost=59498.05..59514.04 rows=1599 width=4)"
"                Group Key: db100.z"
"                ->  Seq Scan on db100  (cost=0.00..51190.84 rows=3322884 width=4)"

Comment: @spoonboy: don't add code in comments. [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39383167/edit) your question instead (and you should **really** show us the output of `explain (analyze)` not the plain `explain`